# Check whether or not Paint objects are visually the same

Tags: android, equals, paint

I was wondering if there is a good way for `Paint` comparison.

For example, consider the following code:

```
Paint paint1 = new Paint();
paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
Paint paint2 = new Paint(paint1);
Paint paint3 = new Paint(paint1);
paint3.setColor(Color.YELLOW);
```

In this case, I would like to write some code that says that:

- `paint1` is the same as `paint2`
- `paint1` and `paint2` are not the same as `paint3`.

Of course, you cannot use e.g., `paint1 == paint2` as these are two different objects. Also, it seems that `paint1.equals(paint2)` is not working.

Is there a way? Or should I individually compare the attributes (such as color, alpha, strokeCap) that I think are important?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look on the Paint class implementation [here](http://androidxref.com/9.0.0_r3/xref/frameworks/base/graphics/java/android/graphics/Paint.java). Check what constructor Paint(Paint p) does, what attr it sets. There is a hidden API method hasEqualAttributes(Paint p). Maybe you can use this method code in your app.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to implement your own checking, maybe with a custom `Comparator` as `Paint` does not override `equals` and `hashcode`.

There is a hidden method on the `Paint` class called : `hasEqualAttributes(@NonNull Paint other)`

This can be used via reflection :

```
    Paint paint1 = new Paint();
    paint1.setColor(Color.BLUE);
    Paint paint2 = new Paint(paint1);
    Paint paint3 = new Paint(paint1);
    paint3.setColor(Color.YELLOW);

    try {
        final Method method = paint1.getClass().getDeclaredMethod("hasEqualAttributes", Paint.class);
        final boolean equal = (boolean) method.invoke(paint1, paint2);
        final boolean equal2 = (boolean) method.invoke(paint2, paint3);
        Log.i("TAG", "Has equal attributes : " + equal);
        Log.i("TAG", "Has equal attributes : " + equal2);
    } catch (NoSuchMethodException | IllegalAccessException | InvocationTargetException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Output :

```
Has equal attributes : true
Has equal attributes : false
```

However this is highly discouraged as implementations can change between API's

Comment: With the first part of your answer: do you mean to create my own Paint class that extends Paint and overrides equals?

Comment: No that does not make sense to extend the entire class for what you deem constitutes as equal between your paint objects.  `Comparator` is an interface that can be used, for instance, to sort a `Collection` but you define what makes the type `<T>` equal or not equal .. depends on the use cases, a `Comparator` is more flexible than say a static utility method as it is a standard Java class that has applications in many APIs in the framework.

Comment: Thanks! I have implemented a `Comparator`, using similar code as used in the hidden method `hasEqualAttributes` in `Paint`. However, I run into two problems: 1. Some of the attributes do not have getters (e.g., `mShadowLayerRadius`) and 2. Some of the provided getters in `Paint` are hidden themselves (e.g., `getWordSpacing`).